# PyTest with Allure and Selenium how to prevent Selenium exceptions from marking the test as broken?

Tags: python, selenium, pytest, allure

So I'm running Selenium for my web tests with PyTest as a test runner and Allure as the reporting tool. The problem i've encountered is that Selenium sometimes throws errors and instead of showing these are test failures Allure shows them as broken tests. An example of this is something like:

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, locator)))
```

This can throw a

> selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException

When Allure sees this it assume it's a bug in the test but when actually it is a bugg that Selenium came across.

So how can I get PyTest to catch the exception and instead raise an assertion error?

Ofc I could do something like this:

```
try:
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, locator)))
....
```

but this will cause alot of code repetition.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `time.sleep()` and then locate the desired element.
Of course it will increase the execution time but maybe you can get rid of the exception

Comment: I want the exception, I just don't want Allure to show the test as broken, the reason I get the exception is because Selenium found a bug. What I want is for PyTest to catch the exception but I don't want to do a try catch each time i use wait.until

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly you want to continue a test even if the search for the element times out.

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

try:
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, locator)))
except TimeoutException:
    print("Timeout Exception: ", TimeoutException)
    # do something else
```

This will capture the `TimeoutException` you are seeing.  You can use the same kind of thing for a bunch of different exceptions you may see when working with elements.

Answer (score 0):

Allure will mark the test as a fail only when there is an Assertion exception. For all other exceptions, it will mark the test as broken.